# Saltstack: is it possible to forbid certain commands when using cmd.run?

Tags: remote-access, saltstack

Let's say I have a salt-master and decide to run some arbitrary command in all my minions. But because I had a bad night, I was robbed on my way to work, my boss yelled at me for being late and my co-workers decided to play on me that nasty joke with pins and needles, instead of doing a harmless:

```
salt '*' cmd.run "rm -rf /var/tmp/some/directory/with/redundant/data"
```

What comes out is:

```
salt '*' cmd.run "rm -rf /"
```

Disaster! Is there any way that I can "blacklist" certain commands so they can't be executed using cmd.run?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was this question answered to your satisfaction?

Comment: Not really. But the only answer is probably right, so I'll mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Not without customizing the source code.

Comment: @slm I believe it does.  He didn't ask howto, he asked if it was possible.  Should I still delete this answer and use the comments?

Comment: @slm This answers the question just fine. Sometimes "No" is the answer.

Comment: No leave it, I missed that he didn't want to know how. Sorry about that.